# How to include less file in xml file in Magento2?

Tags: less, magento2, magento2.4

How to include 'less' file in the particular XML file. I want it to import 'less' file for only on the catalog page. So I tried by creating CSS file and inside the CSS file imported the 'less' file. Then, in XML I have added a CSS file. But it's not worked. How to add 'less' file only for the catalog page or how to include in the particular XML file.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe start to read about pre-processing files works?

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html

If you want to import a new `.less` file in your theme, you have to create an `_extend.less` file in your `Magento_Catalog` theme module.

And in your `_extend.less` add the following CSS rule :

```
@import "path/to/your/file.less";
```

And that's it.

Comment: This is including less file into another less file. I worked out the many way to include the XML file. The only way is to convert less file into css file and then including css file in to particular XML file.